Почему list.remove(num) не убирает элемент?
Нужно удалить через функцию remove() числа. Почему не все удаляются?
nums = [4, 2, 7, 6, 7, 3, 7, 9]
for i in nums:
    nums.remove(i)
print(nums)  # вывод: [2, 6, 3, 9]


Потому что вы изменяете список, по которому проходитесь циклом, что приводит к непредсказуемым последствиям

я изменила код, и все равно тот же самый результат
nums = [4, 2, 7, 6, 7, 3, 7, 9]
nums2 = nums
for i in nums:
nums2.remove(i)
print(nums2)  #вывод: [2, 6, 3, 9]

nums и nums2 ссылаются на один и тот же список, то есть по сути вы ничего не изменили

for i in nums.copy() починит )

for i in nums[::-1]:

@S.Nick В данном случае переворачивать не нужно )

Кстати, очень не рекомендую присваивать имя списку, совпадающее с командой - list. Это у Вас в заголовке такое написано.

@FoxFox так в самом коде тс и не использовал ключевое слово list в названии переменной. Тут скорее типизация ‍♀️

Я вижу итак и видел. Я просто обращаю внимание, что прямо в заголовке написано далеко не лучшее. Более того, там написано ещё и то, что явно следствие незнания даже базы. Когда говорят о методах списков, list. не добавляют. list.remove() - это уже совершенно другое получается.

Три варианта:
nums = [4, 2, 7, 6, 7, 3, 7, 9]
nums_copy = nums.copy()
for i in nums_copy: nums.remove(i)
print(nums)

nums = [4, 2, 7, 6, 7, 3, 7, 9]
nums = [i for i in nums if i not in nums]
print(nums)

nums = [4, 2, 7, 6, 7, 3, 7, 9]
nums = []
print(nums)

